# fest that takes over several blocks of Folsom

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is an excerpt from a Vox article.

> We went to the Folsom Street Fair, too, an adults-only kink-fest that
> **takes** over several blocks of Folsom one weekend every September.

I wonder if the meaning of *takes* in bold is [*to obtain or secure for use (as by lease, subscription, or purchase)*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take).

Comment: ***Takes over*** here is just a somewhat more metaphoric alternative to ***dominates*** - with the sense of *being the most important thing going on at the time*. It doesn't necessarily reflect any formal arrangements legalising / empowering fair-related activities any more than at other times. It's just that when the festival ***is*** ongoing, it affects many other things a lot (so the locals can't easily avoid being aware of it, even if they wanted to).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a phrasal verb "take over" meaning "to get control of something".

Its often used of businesses or countries, but it can be used here to mean that the "kink-fest" (a festival of sexual kinks) gets control of these blocks, in the sense that all the streets are filled with people at the festival.

There's no notion of lease, subscription or purchase. Only that of "occupying territory"

Comment: Thank you very much.